# How the Grid System works for full width page?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, grid, responsive-design

How the grid system works for those websites that expand to the full size of the browser (no matter how you resize) while working with the 12 grid_ system?

For example, take a look on these websites:

http://vevo.com

http://xfinitytv.comcast.net

http://pinterest.com

Is there a technical name for this? Why there's no many websites like this that take advantage of the full browse size?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "technical name" for what you're asking about is called "fluid" layout.  In terms of how to achieve this in Bootstrap, the answer depends on whether you're using v.2.x or the newly released version 3. In version 2.x the fluid effect was obtained by wrapping grid elements in a  with the "container-fluid" class.  In release 3, the "container" class is fluid by default. (See [Bootstrap: Migrating from 2.x to 3.0](http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/#migration) for more.)

As for why more sites don't use fluid layout in all most, that's a rather subjective question. I'll comment from my personal experience (15 years in web design and development)>  The fluid design doesn't really become a problem until you get to larger displays, where having the content stretched out across the entire width of the screen can pose usability problems.  Specifically, block of text can become very difficult to read if the lines become too long. The longer the lines of text, the more difficult it is for the eye to find the start of the next line.  Also, images stretched too wide loose their sharpness (assuming that technique is used). Simply put, people with large displays typically don't want or need the *entire* display taken up by content.  Web applications are an exception to this, since online apps often have grids of data to display and many columns, data panels, menus, etc. that necessitate that the user maximize use of all available display area.  Do a web search for "fluid vs. fixed width layout" and you'll get plenty of resources comparing the two approaches.